# Shortcode not working on Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I have been working on wordpress website. Few days back i changed theme. My previous them was supporting wordpress shortcode. I was using [box type=”shadow”] to creates a shadow box.
E.g

[box type=”shadow”] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.[/box]  and outuput had been displaying like shown in image below

[image]

I don't want to use any plugin for this. I wanna do this with pure code.

Comment: For future reference, you are expected to do your research and make an attempt at the problem yourself before posting here. This isn't a code-writing service. Take a look at [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). In future, make sure your question includes a specific coding question and the code you have tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcode is quiet popular in WordPress.

Here is how it works.

```
function boxShow($atts, $content = null ){
    //default values
    $option = shortcode_atts( array(
         'type' => '',
    ), $atts );

    ob_start(); 

    $class = $option[ 'type' ] ? 'shadow' : 'normal';

    //HTML goes here
    ?>
    <div class="box <?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content; ?></box>

    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'box', 'boxShow' );
```

You can control the design with the class defined with the type of box.

You can use on text editor with this format

```
[box type="shadow"]Your content here[/box]
```

If you want to use as a code level use this format:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[box type="shadow"]this is text[/box]' ); ?>
```

For more understanding about [WordPress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: I added same code. But nothing works. Could you please change and write full code and i will add code in function.php because i have not created any shortcode before and have not knowledge about this. I wanna output like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPSSo.png

Comment: Sorry that i have forgot to add_shortode. Please see my edit on my answer.

Comment: I replaced this code. But nothing works. Here is output   
[box type=”shadow”] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.[/box]

Comment: @Jack I have tried on my end, it worked perfectly. Where have you place this shortcode?

Comment: i am adding this code i function.php before opening  of <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: There are two ways you can use Shortcode either by code level and from text editor of backend. Please look into my editable answer. 
The function should be placed on functions.php

Comment: can you help me on teamviewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189660/discussion-between-mohammad-ashique-ali-and-jack).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a plugin you can write the code direct into the functions.php within your theme folder.

```
// functions.php
function boxShow($atts, $content = null){
     return '<div class="box">'.$content.'</div>';
} 

add_shortcode('box',boxShow);
```

After this you can add the shortcode within your Pages:

```
[box]Text[/box]
```

Look into this guide for more infos:
https://speckyboy.com/getting-started-with-wordpress-shortcodes-examples/

Comment: sorry to disturb you. can you please create full code? i have also shared snapshot.